# Merging MySQL data into the same list

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to do a change log page.
I have the change log content in a database and then I want to display it by date in a PHP page.

Here's the code:

```
$getChangeLog = "SELECT * FROM changelog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
$query = $conn->query($getChangeLog);
echo "<h1>CHANGE LOG</h1>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<h4>".$row["date"]."</h4>";
    echo "<ul><li>".$row["change"]."</li></ul>";
}
```

My SQL Databse:

[image: My SQL databse]

I want to display unordered lists with changes that have same dates.

It should look like this:

[image: Example Database Done]

Comment: You might try changing the query to ORDER BY the date field. That would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getChangeLog = "SELECT * FROM changelog ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC LIMIT 6";      
$query = $conn->query($getChangeLog);
echo "<h1>CHANGE LOG</h1>"; 
$c = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    $list[$c] = $row;
    if($row["date"]!=$list[$c-1]["date"])
        echo ($c==0?"":"</ul>")."<h4>".$row["date"]."</h4><ul>";  
    echo "<li>".$row["change"]."</li>";
    $c++;
 }
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I still get changes in separated lists, I want the ones with the same date to merge into just one list

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But there is a little space between the changes, like they were HTML paragraphs. How do I fix it?

Comment: I am using Chrome and I do not have any problem at all. But I think the code above could meet what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because we do not use the method "group_concat" and "group by" mysql for you to return pooled data.

```
SELECT id, group_concat (change), date FROM changelog GROUP BY date ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6;
```